# How to open a socket after closing it?

Tags: python, sockets

I tried with opening the socket

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

sending a message, and then closing it

```
sock.close()
```

but I don't know how to open it again. I use UDP socket, and the sock.connect() is a TCP command I think... leastways I tried it but it caused error.

Comment: `sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)`

Comment: You open it again the same way you opened it the first time…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reopen a socket. As [`close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) explains:

> The underlying system resource (e.g. a file descriptor) is also closed when all file objects from makefile() are closed. Once that happens, all future operations on the socket object will fail.

This is inherent in the BSD sockets model: closing a socket means the kernel throws away all resources related to that socket and releases the file descriptor. As [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html#) defines it:

> If fildes refers to a socket, close() shall cause the socket to be destroyed.

If you try to use that file descriptor again, you get an `EBADFD` error if you're lucky—and if you're unlucky, you get some completely different socket or file that reused the same number. In fact, this is true for *all* file descriptors, not just sockets. Quoting POSIX again:

> Once a file is closed, the file descriptor no longer exists, since the integer corresponding to it no longer refers to a file.

---

What you *can* do, of course, is create a brand new socket, the same way you created the first one:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

You may end up with a different file descriptor, but for most sockets code, that won't make a difference.

---

Or, of course, you can just not close the socket. Whatever reason you had for wanting to close the socket, the fact that you want to use it again implies that you were probably wrong.